# Program stops working after getc(stdin)

Tags: c, input

```
printf("hello2");
int i = 0;
int done = 0;

while (!done)
{
    char c;
    printf("hello3");
    c = getc(stdin);
    printf("hello4");
    if (isspace(c))
    {
         done = 1;
         ungetc(c, stdin);
         printf("hello5");
    }
}
```

So my program is currently trying to read in input (and in this case specifically, an empty input). However, after I found that my program doesn't work, I tried debugging it via scattering printfs around and it seems to me that after `c = getc(stdin)`, the program stops working? If my theory is right, what's wrong with using `c = getc(stdin)`?

Comment: Insure output is flushed by appending a `\n` to each printed string.  Not enough code to discern the issue.

Comment: Note that `getc()` returns an `int`, typically 257 different values `EOF` and values in the `unsigned char` range.

Comment: Try using `fflush(stdout);` after each call of `printf()` to make sure what should be printed is printed.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe exactly what input you gave; what output you saw and what output you expected

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hitting enter after space? Unless you do specific arrangements, your terminal emulation or wherever you're running the program will not give you every keyboard char that's typed. It will wait until you hit enter, and let you work on the whole line that's written.

Answer (score 0):

Stdin will not flush input characters onto the input stream until the newline character '\n'. So getc(stdin) has nothing to read until you hit enter. If you want to read the console input without hitting enter, you can use getch() function in conio.h library available with Windows compilers. getch() reads a character from stdin without waiting for a newline.